# Hide display settings in Wordpress media edit popup

Tags: wordpress, media, media-library

I want to hide DISPLAY SETTINGS in the Image Details popup - highlighted in this image.

[image]

This section is not under a single div, so could not use jQuery to hide (will ave to hide individual items - seemed hacky). When I checked wp-includes/js/media-views.js there is a section:

```
    /**
     * Reset the attachment display settings defaults to the site options.
     *
     * If site options don't define them, fall back to a persistent user setting.
     *
     * @since 3.5.0
     */
    resetDisplays: function() {
            var defaultProps = wp.media.view.settings.defaultProps;
            this._displays = [];
            this._defaultDisplaySettings = {
                    align: getUserSetting( 'align', defaultProps.align ) || 'none',
                    size:  getUserSetting( 'imgsize', defaultProps.size ) || 'medium',
                    link:  getUserSetting( 'urlbutton', defaultProps.link ) || 'none'
            };
    },
```

But I dont know how to configure/overridew this (if at all possible) to hide the section. Any help is appreciated. My Wordpress version is 4.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to hide those settings. Your solution will always be hacky at the current WP state.

My suggestion is to use jQuery to hide those settings, I think those selectors will give you the right elements:

```
var imgSettings = jQuery( '.embed-media-settings' );

// Only .hide() the settings, do not remove them!
imgSettings.find( '.setting.align' ).hide();
imgSettings.find( '.setting.size' ).hide();
imgSettings.find( '.setting.link-to' ).hide();

// Also hide the first title "Display Options"
imgSettings.find( '.setting.align' ).prev().hide();
```